# Not getting graph in Shiny App in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create small application using Shiny. Below is the data frame for which I am trying to create.

```
data<-data.frame(state=c('AZ','VA','CA','AZ','VA','CA'), city=c('Phoenix','Arlington','SantaClara','Mesa','Richmond','SF'),
                        avg=c(10,15,16,13,14,14), date=c('01/09/2017','01/10/2017','01/11/2017','02/09/2017','02/10/2017','02/10/2017'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So, I am trying to create a graph between date(x-axis) and avg(y-axis). So this graph should change based on the selection from dropdown list of State.For example, for a particular selected state, it should show cities available(in other dropdown) in that state.

Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

statelist<-as.list(data$state)
citylist<-as.list(data$city)
ui <- basicPage(
  # plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  # verbatimTextOutput("info")
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("plot1", label=h3("Select State"), choices = statelist),
    selectInput("plot2", label=h3("Select City"), choices = citylist)
  ),
  plotOutput(outputId="plot")
),

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe(
    {
      state <- input$plot1
      updateSelectInput(session, "plot2", choices = data$city[data$state == state])
    }
  ),
  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(data[data$city == input$plot2 & 
                  data$state == input$plot1],aes(date,avg))
    +geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Dropdown is working perfectly but not getting the graph.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some minor modifications to your code:

- There were some commas in places where they should not be: after the ui constructor, and after the observe constructor.
- There was a comma missing in `data[data$city == input$plot2 & 
         data$state == input$plot1,]`
- I edited your observe to be an observeEvent
- I modified the plot to show that it actually changes, since the sample data is quite limited.

Hope this helps!

---

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data<-data.frame(state=c('AZ','VA','CA','AZ','VA','CA'), city=c('Phoenix','Arlington','SantaClara','Mesa','Richmond','SF'),
                 avg=c(10,15,16,13,14,14), Date=c('01/09/2017','01/10/2017','01/11/2017','02/09/2017','02/10/2017','02/10/2017'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

statelist<-unique(data$state)
citylist<-unique(data$city)
ui <- basicPage(
  # plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  # verbatimTextOutput("info")
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("plot1", label=h3("Select State"), choices = statelist),
    selectInput("plot2", label=h3("Select City"), choices = citylist)
  ),
  plotOutput(outputId="plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$plot1,
    {
      state <- input$plot1
      updateSelectInput(session, "plot2", choices = data$city[data$state == state])
    }
  )

  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    data = data[data$city == input$plot2 & 
           data$state == input$plot1,]
        ggplot(data,aes(Date,avg)) + geom_point(size=5) + ggtitle(paste0(input$plot1," - ",input$plot2 ))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Florian. I want Month/Year on the y-axis and bar or line graph. Can you help with it?

Comment: That seems like a new question. Please consider posting that as a new question on Stack Overflow.